# Где сохраняется файл сборки?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, redux

Создал на примере одного из руководств заготовку для по React + Redux - https://github.com/keslo/React-Redux-environment

Скачиваю.
Устанавливаю пакеты через `npm install`
Запускаю проект через `npm start`
Все работает.

Но!

Файл сборки в папке проекта не появляется. Хотя по адресу после запуска `localhost:3000/static/bundle.js` сборка присутствует. Но директории `statiс` и файла в папке проекта нет.

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что он создается в виртуальной директории и выкидывается вебпаком. Чтобы у тебя файлы появились надо запускать команду `webpack`, тогда по настройкам `webpack.config.js` у тебя создадутся нужные тебе файлы.

То что происходит это правильное поведение. Не волнуйся.

PS. Если команда `webpack` в главной директории не вызывается установи его глобально `npm i -g webpack`

Пример того что выдаст `webpack`:

```
> reactjs@1.0.0 webpack-dev \Core\core2\core\gui\web\navigator
> webpack --config=./.config/webpack-dev.config

Compile navigator development
Hash: da962bf7ff67ea98b366
Version: webpack 1.12.15
Time: 5873ms
             Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
navigator.debug.js  202 kB       0  [emitted]  bundle
    + 68 hidden modules
```

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек!

Comment: И такой вопрос. У меня есть JSON файл данных в директории static. Там же где и сборка. Как будет выглядеть ссылка в XmlHttpRequest чтобы обратиться к нему? Чтобы соотнести это я и стал искать файл сборки.

Comment: @AntonK. все куда выкидывается сборка, видимо у тебя это папка `static` создаешь её, закидываешь туда файлы, они должны быть доступны